# How to add custom description to Galleria in Rails app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, galleria, caption

I am using Galleria (classic) and I can't get it to add custom description on images.
Otherwise the gallery works fine, only I see the img file name in caption.

I'm trying to use the dataConfig function - http://galleria.io/docs/options/dataConfig/.  I am not that good at JavaScript so I can't really see what I'm doing wrong.

My code:

```
 <div id="galleria">
   <% for image in @trip.images %>  
   <%= link_to image_tag(image.image.url(:thumb)), image.image.url(:large) %> 
 <span class="desc"> <%= image.title %>  </span>
   <% end %>
</div>
<script>

    Galleria.run('#galleria');
    Galleria.configure({
         minScaleRatio: 1.5,
         maxScaleRatio: 3,
         dataConfig: function(img) { return { description: $(img).next('.desc').html() }; }

   });

</script>
</div>
```

Can You please help ?
Thank you!

**Update:**  generated HTML code

```
 <div id="galleria">
   <a  href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/Thrill/images/439/large/14d8868ac166ce1.54701969.JPG?1326357617"><img alt="14d8868ac166ce1.54701969" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/Thrill/images/439/thumb/14d8868ac166ce1.54701969.JPG?1326357617" /></a>  
   <span class="desc" style=""> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span>
   <a href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/Thrill/images/440/large/14c77a671ced5e4.22721576.JPG?1326357627"><img alt="14c77a671ced5e4.22721576" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/Thrill/images/440/thumb/14c77a671ced5e4.22721576.JPG?1326357627" /></a>   
   <span class="desc" style=""> bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb </span>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you please post the generated HTML code?

Comment: Yes, you can see it in my update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work: http://jsfiddle.net/7g7am/

```
Galleria.run('#galleria', {
    dataConfig: function(img) {
        return {
            description: $(img).parent().next('.desc').html()
        };
    }
});
​
```

Comment: Yes, I changed the code as in your example and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it but I see that Your image is inside an  tag, and you are trying to navigate to  starting from  tag. First you have to move to the parent and then navigage to next tag.

```
$(img).parent().next('.desc').html()
```

Hope it's the solution.

Comment: Thanks, but still no changes after this.

Comment: It should navigate well, maybe there are other problems. Have you noticed any JS errors?